# Autopopulate a full table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Is there any way of autopopulating a full table in excel eg, when a heading is listed it will bring up a table from another sheet based on the heading?

To explain a bit better, I work in a lab and I'm wanting to populate a table which tells you how to make a standard curve based on the name of the test you type in to a certain cell.

There will be information above where I want the table that applies to all tests so it is only the standard curve that is different, which is why I want that to appear based on the name instead of having to make a sheet for every single test.

I'm newish to excel so sorry if this is a stupid question!!

I've used V-lookup for the info at the top which is just serial numbers and dates, but I don't think it works for a full table.

Comment: It would be helpful to see sample data and expected results

Comment: 1. how big is the table (how many columns/row) ? 2. Is the table size the same for all headings option?  3.Is the sheet is the same as the 'heading' you've mentioned? 4. No question is stupid. It just that we need to know how to reproduce the case you'd mentioned and without a sample data/file (with the sheet name/tables to load), it is quite challenging for others to reproduce the case and assist. ( :

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it via `FILTER()` though it will feel a bit odd examining the formula.

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(H1," ","")&"[#All]"),INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(H1," ","")&"[#All]"),,1)=INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(H1," ","")&"[#All]"),,1))
```

Usually with `FILTER()`, when you want all the rows of data in your result, you use a criteria like A2:A1982=A2:A1982 which cannot help but be TRUE as each item WILL equal itself. You do the same sometimes with formulas for Conditional Formatting.

That won't work with `FILTER()` though and I used to think it was due to it not being willing to take the input range if the input range was not a simple Ax:By address. Tables and SPILL ranges for example. Then I found that you really just need to make the address however, continue the formula to get Excel to accept it as a cell formula while not caring what its output is, and edit the formula highlighting the array reference you put in and pressing F9. Once you see what Excel resolves it to, you realize it is NOT the formal thing you are using in your criteria. Rather, it is just a stupid simple array. If you then make the criteria using the precise form of data F9 showed you, or, as above, not even bother, just use the full expression you used for it setting that equal to itself, `FILTER()` finally comes through for you.

So, you can build the array address that `FILTER()` is to use via `INDIRECT()` so that the name of the test can be entered somewhere and then used by the formula.

I used formal Tables as it sounded like you are doing that giving them names based upon the test name (for my work, "Test1", Test2", and so on, but yours would presumably be more aptly named. I also assumed people might enter "Test 2" rather than "Test2" and used `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove the space/s that could occur. If you have them enter simply a name, say "Horse", it will still work perfectly fine though. You just have to name your Tables to match the expected thing users will type, or better yet, add a dropdown list (needing also to create said list) and validation to ensure they pick (or type) something from the list.

Once you have the formal Table name created by Excel, it turns out `FILTER()`uses it to collect data for an internal array looking something like:

```
{"Column1","Column2";"e",5;"f",6;"g",7;"h",8;"i",9;"j",10}
```

It no longer has the Table feature's nice column addressing in it. It's just a simple array. If one uses `INDEX()` wrapped around the exact `INDIRECT()` used to specify the Table, one can select a column or seven and rows, as needed to create the appropriate criteria, but just a simple one is needed here as one wants to get the entire Table's contents, not limit the return.

Hence using the `INDIRECT()` as I did, first to specify the source data, then to tell the testing half to bring over anything, including headers, in the Table which matches itself... in short, everything in the Table including headers.

You want to include headers because you want the return to have headers. AND because `FILTER()` breaks if the rows total in the criteria range does not match the rows total in the data array specified in the first half. To come without headers, you'd need to complicate the `INDIRECT()` for the data array, though that is actually pretty easy.

So you use `FILTER()`, you do not directly specify the criteria via a literal range or one dependent upon Table addressing, and you have to figure out how to make sure the test name the user enters will become the Table name.